# How to get the complete css information if css class is given form the used style sheets files

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firebug, stylesheet

I want to find the complete css information of applied class in details by clicking on it. Like

```
<div class="class1 class2">This is my div</div>
```

Suppose I've written css in xyz.css file

```
.class1{
   background-color:#999999;
   width:auto;
   overflow:hidden;
}

.class2{
   background-color:#856241;
   width:500px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

After clicking on the div I want to display all the css information which is applied to the div.
jQuery solution will be preferred.

As per first few answers I'm getting all the computed style but I'm interested in my only applied class style details.

Comment: I believe, you'd have to write a parser for that. If you just want to view it, check out [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) in combination with Firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the current style of an element with this:

```
var elem = ...;
var css = document.defaultView ? document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem, null) : elem.currentStyle;

if ('length' in css) {
    // iterate over all property names
    for (var i = 0, l = css.length; i < l; ++i) {
        var propertyName = css[i];
        // get property value
        var value = css[propertyName];
        if (value != void 0) {
            console.log(propertyName+': '+value);
        }
    }
} else {
    // IE
    for (var propertyName in css) {
        // get property value
        var value = css[propertyName];
        if (value != void 0) {
            console.log(propertyName+': '+value);
        }
    }
}
```

Try this here: http://jsfiddle.net/P5WYC/2/

You may also whant to try with document.styleSheets ( see http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html )

Comment: I've tried your solution its good, But I'm getting all the information I want only my class information which I've used. I know all the information does matters. In my case I want only those class information. Thanks for your reply. One more thing your fiddle code did't worked when I've clicked on run. I was using chrome was it a problem?

Answer (score -1):

You could do:

```
<div class="class1 class2" id='myId'>This is my div</div>

elem = document.getElementById('myId');
var cssRules = (getComputedStyle || currentStyle)(elem);
var properties = {};

for (var i = 0, l = cssRules.length; i < l; ++i) {
    var propertyName = cssRules[i];

    var value = cssRules.getPropertyValue(propertyName);
    properties[propertyName] = value;
}
```

And properties is an object that has all the css properties of your div